# Custom component update failed saying Failed to copy site files

Tags: installation, joomla-3.4

When I update my custom developed component it throws the below error

```
Warning
JInstaller: :Install: File already exists /path/controller.php
Component Update: Failed to copy site files.
```

Initially I thought it was because of file permission issue but it doesn't look like that.

While debugging the core code I found the problem happens in copyFiles method under /libraries/cms/installer/installer.php where the overwrite flag is set to false.

What could be the problem? In my XML I have method='update' only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your installer xml file, you should use method="upgrade", not update:

eg.

```
<extension method="upgrade" type="package" version="3.0">
```

Comment: Mybad... Yes, you are correct